# Visual Studio doesn't open scripts

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to work on a 2019 unity project but when I try to edit scripts in Microsoft Visual Studio, it says it's not compatible (that it wasn't created for Visual Studio Tools for unity) and to set preferences selecting Visual Studio (already done it). Is it because I have Visual Studio 2022? What can I do to fix this? Thanks!

I tried to check on Edit > Preferences and Visual Studio 2022 is the one set to open my script:

[image]

Comment: Please attach an image of the error. Also specify how you tried to open the script files: from Unity by double clicking, from File Explorer by double clicking on the `cs`, by opening the `sln` manually from File Explorer etc.

Comment: Using VS2022 should not be a problem. Have you installed the Unity package for VS using the VS installer?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/jz2XXNk i try to open them through the unity editor and this is what i get. I have in italian but basically it says that it wasn't created for Visual Studio Tools for unity. 
Also i've installed the unity package so i really don't know why it keeps telling me this :(

Comment: Show us the C# individual components from VS2022, please!

Comment: How can i do that? I really don't know. By the way I've worked with Visual Studio 2022 and Unity 2021 and I had no problem at all...

Answer (score 0):

Checking out these might help:

1. Ensure that you've installed the Visual Studio for Unity package, from the package manager window.
2. Double-check that you've Unity development workload installed in the Visual Studio Installer application.
3. Do not open the scripts from VS or file explorer. Double-click on them from the Unity Editor's project window.

If those things didn't solve your problem, also check these out:

1. Create an empty project & test if the problem is solved or not
2. Update Visual Studio to the latest version
3. Install the latest minor release of your current Unity installation (For instance if you have installed Unity 2021.1..., update to 2021.3....)

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/XxoXqI6 as you can see here it says that i have installed the visual studio for unity package. Also, i always open the script by clicking on them through the unity editor. Sorry to be a bother but i don't understand what you mean in the second point..... Sorry but i'm new in this field.

Comment: Oh, please provide any other information that might help with the question. Also, check out the edit of my answer.

Comment: I've updated Visual studio to the latest version but it still doesn't work. The thing is I've already worked on a project on Unity 2021.3.19f1 and it worked fine, i managed to make scripts without problems. Now I'm trying to open a project of 2019 of another person (Unity 2019.3.0a4) and this problem popped up. I don't want to be a bother but i'm really new to all of this so sometimes i really don't know how to provide some informations.